Unnumbered sections are being ignored for page header
I have pieced together a nice page design with header/footer that works just as I want it to, with one exception: when I use \section*{} to exclude the numbering of the section, I guess the header line doesn't recognize the section as such and either leaves the header blank, or uses the header of the previous section, if any exists. I don't have the issue with \tableofcontents or \listoffigures, just with normal sections. Any ideas on how to get the unnumbered section into my header? MWE below:
EDIT: simply place \markboth{Abstract}{} after \section*{}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\leftmark}} } %leftmark gives just section
\def\Vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.9ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\fancyfoot{\Vhrulefill~\thepage~\Vhrulefill}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman} 
\vspace*{\fill}
\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contents}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\newpage 
\section* {List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage 
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}


This is standard, in most classes the starred version does not write to TOC or to headers. You already know what to do for toc. For headers you can use \markboth{text}{text} or \markright{text}
